# declaring constraint/polymorphic types in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, static-typing

In Haskell (and [chicken scheme](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Types)) you can declare constrained types,
for example `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` declares
that `map` will take a list containing the type of the function input, and return a list containing the function output.
Is the same possible in common lisp function declarations?
Could I do something analogous like this:

```
(declaim (ftype (function (function (a) b)
                          (list a))
                (list b)
                map))
```

"you can't do that" would be a satisfactory answer :)

Comment: Could you use [listp](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_listp.htm) to check to see if your args are, in fact, lists?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica hmm, not sure what you mean. I can already know how to declare the input and return value as a list, what I want to do is specify that the type in the list agrees with the function.

Comment: in [this page](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/type.html) from the Lisp Cookbook, under "Type Checking" it says "Common Lisp supports run-time type checking via the macro `check-type`. It accepts a place and a type specifier as arguments and signals an type-error if the contents of place are not of the given type". Perhaps that's a starting point.

Comment: Even if you could declare them, what would you do with them? Common Lisp as a standard does not define any static type checking. One would need to look for extensions of Common Lisp and/or specific implementations, which would provide static type checking.

Comment: See also https://github.com/stylewarning/coalton

Comment: @RainerJoswig I use SBCL which catches a lot of type errors at compile time, when I declare them. This is the feature I want most, as well as conveying intent/usage to readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in a single type declaration.  We don't have type variables.